# Is it a bad practice to create multiple similar public methods that wrap a private method?

Tags: php, class, oop, object, architecture

I have this class which performs subroutines with side effects by taking in certain domain objects.

These domain objects are different classes yet they have some similarities. I am wondering how to structure a service in terms of making many public methods that wrap a private method with parameters or just make one public method with more parameters.

**Case One:**

```
class MyService {
     private MethodWithManyParameters($a, $b, $c, $d, $similarParameterA, $similarParameterB)   {
          // do things
          if ($similarParameterA == $objectTypeA) {
               // code
          }
          else if ($similarParameterB == $objectTypeB) {
               // other really similar code
          }

     }


     public DoThingsWithObjectA($a, $b, $c, $d) {
          // $this->MethodWithManyParameters($a, $b, $c, $d, $objectTypeA, $variableA);
     }

     public DoThingsWithObjectB($a, $b, $c, $d) {
          // $this->MethodWithManyParameters($a, $b, $c, $d, $objectTypeB, $variableB);
     }
}

// application code
MyService->DoThingsWithObjectA(...);
MyService->DoThingsWithObjectB(...);
```

**Case Two**

```
class MyService {
     public DoThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d, $similarParameterA, $similarParameterB)   {
          // do things
          if ($similarParameterA == $objectTypeA) {
               // code
          }
          else if ($similarParameterB == $objectTypeB) {
               // other really similar code
          }
     }
 }

 // application code
 MyService->DoThingsWithObject(........); // this one has a bigger argument list
```

I'm trying to think of pros and cons for both approaches.

First approach:

Pros:
 - simplified application code, in the case where a lot of parameters are used it can remove some

Cons:
 - introduces more coupling, since if an objectC is introduced, then MyService also has to be changed to accommodate it

Second approach:

Pros:
 - simplified class with less methods
 - more flexible

Cons: 
 - argument lists can be bigger when you have to deal with differences between objects

For now it appears that just having one public function is good, but the second method looks cleaner at first because it deals with things more abstractly.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are doing similar things with various objects, chances are these objects share certain properties/methods: create an abstract base class, or implement an interface, that allows you to use just one method, and let the classes implement various methods differently to deal with their differences. However, if both objects are entirely different, then two entirely separate methods should be implemented

Comment: So in your first point if ObjectA and ObjectB are quite similar, then I just create two classes: MyServiceA and MyServiceB which both have DoThingsWithObject which is inherited from AbstractMyService?

And if the objects are different enough, the current first approach is sufficient with two separate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not.

Check a very commonly used case:

```
class ConsoleClass {

     protected /* void */ InternalWrite(/* string */ $SomeValue)   {
          // do things
     } // void InternalWrite(...)

     public /* void */ WriteStr(/* string */ $SomeValue) {
          InternalWrite($SomeValue);
     }

     public /* void */ WriteInt(/* int */ $SomeValue) {
          $SomeString = (string)$SomeValue;
          InternalWrite($SomeString);
     }

     public /* void */ WriteArray(/* array */ $SomeValue) {
          $SomeString = "";

          $SomeString .= "[";
          foreach ($SomeValue as $index => $value)
          {
            $SomeString .= (string)$value;
            $SomeString .= ",";
          } // foreach
          $SomeString .= "[";

          InternalWrite($SomeString);
     }

} // class

// application code
$Console = new ConsoleClass()

$Console->WriteStr("Hello World");
$Console->WriteInt(5);
$Console->WriteArray(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Just My 2 cents.

[UPDATE:] Changed "private" to "protected".

Comment: Thanks, this makes a very clear example. However, what if you have a new type with a particular console standard output representation.

What about doing something like,

http://pastebin.com/V9RHvGYe

where you can write arbitrary objects as long as they have a representation. This way your console class is a lot more flexible since it can take any object with a particular implementation.

However, this also mixes up view logic in the object, since now it has to know how to represent itself.

Thoughts?

Comment: @Viktor Chynarov Yes, I agree. Before I was going to browse the example, I was going to add a similar example to objects. Remember your question its about using private / protected functions by other public methods ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that stands out is the use of the `if, elseif` in either cases. In object oriented design, this is nearly always a case for abstracting out the code:

```
abstract class MyService
{
    abstract public function doThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d);
}

class ObjectA extends MyService
{
    public function doThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d)
    {
        print "Implementation for ObjectA";
    }
}

class ObjectB extends MyService
{
    public function doThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d)
    {
        print "Implementation for ObjectB";
    }
}
```

And then to use the code:

```
$objectA = new ObjectA();
$objectB = new ObjectB();

$objectA->doThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d); // Implementation for ObjectA
$objectB->doThingsWithObject($a, $b, $c, $d); // Implementation for ObjectB
```

Comment: Yes I understand this, but the case is that in code MyService is more complex and has to interact with other objects, for instance RepositoryC and RepositoryD. In this case, I don't want to add these things to ObjectA and ObjectB because they have their own domain-specific business logic and the purpose of MyService is doing operations with them based on other classes.

Comment: In which case, inject the dependent objects into the constructor. Are you familiar with Dependency Injection?

Comment: Yes I am and I have DIC containers to instantiate my controllers, but which constructor am I injecting things into, MyService or ObjectA?

Comment: This will depend on your business needs, and what makes sense to the code. Often this is only realised by choosing an option, and seeing how it goes. I would inject them into your base class first, and see if you find a need to extract them out into your child classes